# React Native Navigation - Always fade out from specific screen

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-navigation

one of my screens is my splash screen, and I want to always fade out from this screen, but I dont want to configure all my screens to `options={{ animation: 'fade' }}` I want to apply a solution only to my splash screen.
Thanks !

Comment: Are you using any lib to work with the splash screen? Like this one https://github.com/crazycodeboy/react-native-splash-screen. Because these libs already have a method to make the screen fade out.

Comment: @GabrielMenezesdaSilva
No, I am not using any libraries, but the splash screen is only an example, I want to be able to do this also on other screens..
But thank you for your answer :)